# Knockout.js is returning an undefined event for the focus binding in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I am attempting to use Knockout.js and the jQuery autosize plugin for a comment stream system. Basically, when a comment input is focused, I use the Knockout.js event binding shown below:

```
data-bind="event: {focus: $parent.autosize, blur: $parent.resize}"
```

In my model, I implement the `autosize` function as follows:

```
$self.autosize = function(data, event) {
    var textarea = $(event.target);
    textarea.autosize();
});
```

From what I can tell, however, `event` is `undefined`, and I am unable to use it to find the textarea so that I can call `autosize()` on it. I am also unable to query the textarea's attributes, and when I use `console.log` to find the value of `event` I am given `undefined` back.

This *only* appears to be happening in Internet Explorer. Particularly version 8-9. IE 10 as well as Chrome, Firefox, etc. work as expected. Is there a known issue with Knockout.js event binding and Internet Explorer in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE you would need to access `event.srcElement` rather than `event.target`.  So, you could do `var textArea = $(event.target || event.srcElement);`

A more "Knockout" like solution though would be to add a quick custom binding that would keep that logic out of your view model like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autosize = {
  init: function(element) {
      ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "focus", function() {
          $(element).autosize();
      });

      ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "resize", function() {
           //whatever you call here
      });

  }
};
```

Then, just put `data-bind="autosize: true"` on your element.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan's answers is a great solution to the "autosize" problem, but I also would like to further explain the issue of the lack of `event.target`. When using jQuery to handle events, jQuery will standardize the `event` object to include `target` even if the browser doesn't include it.

Knockout will use jQuery for event handling if it's present (and thus provide `event.target`), but to do so, jQuery needs to be present when Knockout is *loaded*. Simply, then, you should always include jQuery before Knockout in your HTML if you want proper integration of the two.